# C - Array type has incomplete element type for array of structs

Tags: c, struct

```
typedef char line_t[MAX_INPUT + 1];

struct {
    line_t line;
    double score;
    int linenumber;
} line_rank;

struct line_rank lines[MAX_LINES + 1];
```

Produces this : `error: array type has incomplete element type` which refers to the last line in the code I have provided.

I have looked everywhere and can't seem to find another question relating to structs manipulated in such a way.

Comment: The type `struct line_rank` is incomplete, because it has not be defined anywhere.

Comment: @pablo1977 I don't understand? The third last line of the code has the previous struct declared as line_rank?

Comment: No, there you have defined an anonymous struct and a global variable `line_rank` having this type.

Comment: @pablo1977 Ahhh, so it's a typedef issue as MikeCAT has answered. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to add `typedef` and delete `struct`.

```
typedef char line_t[MAX_INPUT + 1];

typedef struct {
    line_t line;
    double score;
    int linenumber;
} line_rank;

line_rank lines[MAX_LINES + 1];
```